# Что означает переменная перед for при минимизации кода

Tags: python

Я захотел написать код в минимальное количество строк и столкнулся вот с этим `[i for i in x]`. Объясните, пожалуйста, что означает i перед for?

Comment: https://pythontutor.ru/lessons/for_loop/

Answer (score 3):

То с чем вы столкнулись - является *генератором*. `i` перед `for` означает что генератор будет возвращать значение `i`. Таким образом можно сгенерировать список. Несколько примеров:

```
>>> [i for i in range(4)]
#Вывод: [0, 1, 2, 3]

>>> [i.upper() for i in ['a', 'b', 'c']]
#Вывод: ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Генераторы довольно сложно понять. Поэтому, возможно, вы будете долго разбираться с ними. Для начала прочтите [это](https://pythonru.com/uroki/30-generatory-dlja-nachinajushhih).

Answer (score 0):

То, о чем вы спрашиваете по-русски называется "генератор списков", только требует того, что-бы его употребляли в квадратных скобках. Читайте тут

https://webdevblog.ru/kogda-ispolzovat-list-comprehension-v-python/

Answer (score 0):

i - название значения в for (Ну или генератор)

То есть когда ты вызываешь цикл тебе нужно написать переменную куда будет поступать цифра, класс, строка и т.д
А этот самый `i` и есть переменная для for. (i for i in x)

```py
true = True
some_text = "Yes" if true else "No" # Ставит "Yes" Т.к true = True
```

Это ещё один пример.

Такие сокращения можно использовать и в f"{i for i in x}" И т.д
Главное знать как их использовать

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).